# Flattening two tables and using a group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two transaction tables like this:

```
TableA

 X  R  S
 71 1 10 
 71 2 20
 71 3 30 
 72 1 40 
 72 2 50
 72 3 60

TableB


 X  P Q
 71 1 110 
 71 2 120
 71 3 130 
 73 1 140 
 73 2 150
 73 3 160
```

I want to flatten the table and execute a query which gives me a result like this:

```
  X  S1  S2  S3   Q1  Q2  Q3

  71 10  20  30  110 120 130
  72 40  50  60   0    0   0
  73  0   0   0  140 150 160
```

where the subscripts in S and Q denote the value of the third column when the second column equals the subscript. For example, S1 denotes the `S` column value when second column is equal to 1, or Q2 denotes the value of `Q` when the second column is 2.

I can't figure out what is the best way to about it. Maybe I can use a case statement or may be a subquery. But honestly I have no concrete idea of going about it.

Comment: Will there always be 3 `R` values and 3 `P` values for each `X`?

Comment: No.. Its not necessary that it be the case always !!

Comment: It would help greatly if you told everyone what database you're using. Also, this is normally something you would want to undo rather than do (or at least handle in the application), but I suppose there could be a use case for it.

Comment: Well I am using the mysql database, and the solution given by Gordon uses `full outer join` which we can't use in MySQL !!  But still this helps immensely in terms of figuring out the way. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to do this with a join and two aggregations:

```
select coalesce(a.x, b.x) as x, a.s1, a.s2, a.s3, b.q1, b.q2, b.q3
from (select x,
             max(case when r = 1 then s end) as s1,
             max(case when r = 2 then s end) as s2,
             max(case when r = 3 then s end) as s3
      from tableA a
      group by x
     ) a full outer join
     (select x,
             max(case when p = 1 then q end) as q1,
             max(case when p = 2 then q end) as q2,
             max(case when p = 3 then q end) as q3
      from tableb b
      group by x
     ) b
     on a.x = b.x;
```

EDIT:

If you want to avoid the nested subqueries, you could try:

```
select coalesce(a.x, b.x) as x,
       max(case when r = 1 then s end) as s1,
       max(case when r = 2 then s end) as s2,
       max(case when r = 3 then s end) as s3
       max(case when p = 1 then q end) as q1,
       max(case when p = 2 then q end) as q2,
       max(case when p = 3 then q end) as q3
from TableA a full outer join
     TableB b
     on a.x = b.x and a.r = b.p
group by coalesce(a.x, b.x);
```

It might even be more efficient.

Comment: Your query runs correctly but it only return entries corresponding to the row where `X=71`. I needed all the rows !!

Comment: @OneMoreError . . . Oops, I missed in the question that the values of `x` are not the same in the two tables.  This is fixed by switching to a `full outer join`.

Comment: Ya.. got it !! Btw can we do it using only one query ( with no nested subquery ) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
ISNULL(A.x, B.x) AS x, SUM(CASE WHEN R = 1 THEN S ELSE 0 END) AS S1,
SUM(CASE WHEN R = 2 THEN S ELSE 0 END) AS S2,
SUM(CASE WHEN R = 3 THEN S ELSE 0 END) AS S3,
SUM(CASE WHEN P = 1 THEN Q ELSE 0 END) AS Q1,
SUM(CASE WHEN P = 2 THEN Q ELSE 0 END) AS Q2,
SUM(CASE WHEN P = 3 THEN Q ELSE 0 END) AS Q3 
FROM tableA A FULL JOIN tableB B ON A.X = B.X
GROUP BY ISNULL(A.x, B.x)
```

T-SQL version